# procedure prolog explanation

Tags: assembly, stack, stack-overflow, subroutine

I am quite new to this and have some questions that I would appreciate your help to understand it.

> The first thing a procedure must do when called is save the previous
>   FP (so it can be restored at procedure exit).  Then it copies SP into
>   FP to create the new FP, and advances SP to reserve space for the
>   local variables. This code is called the procedure prolog.  Upon
>   procedure exit, the stack must be cleaned up again, something called
>   the procedure epilog.  The Intel ENTER and LEAVE instructions and the
>   Motorola LINK and UNLINK instructions, have been provided to do most
>   of the procedure prolog and epilog work efficiently.

The above text is quoted from smashing the stack paper and I found it quite hard to understand the following questions:

> "The first thing a procedure must do when called is save the previous
>   FP (so it can be restored at procedure exit).  Then it copies SP into
>   FP to create the new FP"

1) does copying the SP to FP erases the saved FP value -which is supposed to be saved?

> "Then it copies SP into FP to create the new FP, and advances SP to
>   reserve space for the local variables."

2) why the need to advance the SP ? is not it supposed to be decremented automatically when local variables are pushed in?

3) what is the value of both SP, IP and FP when starting the main function without calling any subroutine?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) does copying the SP to FP erases the saved FP value -which is supposed to be saved?

Copying the stack pointer to the frame pointer register (e/bp on Intel) overwrites the previous value, yes, but you just saved that value on stack in the previous step precisely so that it can be restored on exit.

> 2) why the need to advance the SP ? is not it supposed to be decremented automatically when local variables are pushed in?

Yes, `push` does that but this step is usually done with a `mov` (on Intel), which does not modify the stack pointer.

> 3) what is the value of both SP, IP and FP when starting the main function without calling any subroutine?

IP points to the first instruction in `main`, obviously. The stack pointer points to the last item saved on stack. The frame pointer typically points to the frame of the operating system function that invoked `main`.